# WinHttpCertCfg installs certificates to unknown location

Tags: certificate, winhttpcertcfg

I am using winhttpcertcfg to install a certificate into "Certificates (Local Computer) / Personal / Certificates" (MMC)

```
winhttpcertcfg -i "C:\test.pfx" -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -p removedForQuestion
```

Running this command shows the following output (no errors, but nothing suggesting it has worked either:

> Microsoft (R) WinHTTP Certificate Configuration Tool
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001.

When I search for the certificate (I checked Current User as well as Local Computer) there is nothing to see in MMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works just fine with `certutil`, so I'm using that instead of `winhttpcertcfg` for the install and then granting permissions separately.

```
certutil -f -p removedForQuestion -importpfx "C:\test.pfx"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several complexities to be considered while choosing an alternative for winhttpcertcfg.

See answer

https://serverfault.com/questions/620013/importing-a-certificate-and-granting-permissions-on-windows-server-2012-r2/622556#622556

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx

> -i    Specifies that the certificate is to be imported from a Personal Information Exchange (PFX) file. This parameter must be followed by
>   the name of the file. **When this parameter is specified, "-a" and "-c"
>   must also be specified.**